# How to move a class and the namepsace using PhpStorm?

Tags: php, refactoring, phpstorm, automated-refactoring

I just tried moving a class in PhpStorm 10.0.3 using F6, yet it only changed the file's location and not its namesapce. Manually adapting the namespace feels wrong, especially if the class has been used at multiple places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the cursor upon the classe's definition, and then press F6. This will open the move class dialog and there your have the option to move it to a different namepsace.

```
class Foo 
{
}
```

The cursor has to be on `Foo`.

One has to both specify the target namespace and target destination directory. Then refactoring works as expected.

If you press only F6 when your cursor is inside any other place in the class file, phpstorm will only open up the move dialog.

Comment: Isn't this more like a PHPstorm support forum post than OS topic?

Comment: @rst I think it covers both "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" as pointed out by the [ontopic help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Feel free to flag it as off-topic and we'll let the community decide.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it just seems odd.